# How to use multiple forms / actions in a single view in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

I have a search box which is displayed on every page. The JSP code for the search box is inserted into every page via tiles.

The search box has a form and an action class `SearchAction` which needs to preload some properties for drop down boxes. The `SearchAction` class has an `input()` method, which does this initialization.

Some pages also have their own form in the main area. Also with their own action class. They also have an `input()` method which does some preloading.

1. Is it possible to use two actions in the same view?
2. How can each form have access to it's own actions's properties.
3. And how could I manage to have the input method of both action classes be called before the JSP is rendered?

**Update:**

I am adding a trimmed down example, since it's probably not clear what I am trying to do. It's a register page `register.jsp` with an `RegisterAction`. And the page also contains the search form. *(BTW: I left out the getter/setter and other stuff in the action classes to keep it short)*:

**`register.jsp`:**

```
<s:form action="executeSearch">
    <s:textfield key="name" label="Name"/>
    <s:textfield key="age"  label="Age"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>

<s:form action="executeRegister">
    <s:textfield key="firstName" label="First Name"/>
    <s:textfield key="lastName" label="Last Name"/>
    <s:textfield key="age" label="Age"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="*Search" class="action.SearchAction" method="{1}">
    <result name="success">/searchresult.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="*Register" class="action.RegisterAction" method="{1}">
    <result name="input">/register.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/registerOk.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**`SearchAction.java`:**

```
public class SearchAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    @Override
    public String input() throws Exception {
        // preload the search form with some demo data
        name = "test";
        age = 20;
        return INPUT;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

**`RegisterAction.java`:**

```
public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    @Override
    public String input() throws Exception {
        // preload the register form with some demo data
        firstName = "John";
        lastName = "Rambo";
        age = 10;
        return INPUT;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Let's say I call the action `inputRegister.action`. Then `RegisterAction.input()` is called. The properties are set. And result `SUCCESS` causes `register.jsp` to be rendered.

But what about my search form. How do I get access to the search action and it's model. Neither of those are on the `ValueStack` of course. And neither do I see a way to call any methods of `SearchAction` in order to initialize it's model. I deliberately choose `age` to be in both action classes. In the rendered page you can see that the search form also accesses the `RegisterAction-*.properties` (because that's on top of the `ValueStack`). But it needs to access `SearchAction`. It must display 20 and not 10.

[image: Rendered Jsp Page]

I am clearly doing it wrong. But even after a lot of googling, I still did't find out the right way to do it.

Comment: Don't use `input` to pre-load values. You can use `preparable` if you need to. You can have one action for navigating to form-s page and others for submitting from forms.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of the view is used to perform any number of actions, and any action can have any number of results. A result is used to return a view. The action that returns a view is placed on top of the `ValueStack` to be easy accessible via evaluating OGNL expressions. The result view could be mapped to any action in any action class. It knows nothing about action which calls it, but it can determine it, again using OGNL. You can map actions to different method of the same action class, so you don't need to have many `input()` methods.

EDIT:

You problem is you bounded form fields wrong. Each form should have a separate storage to display it correctly. Fields are bounded by name, and you'd better have a form bean for the search condition variables and put it somewhere in the action context.

```jsp
<s:form action="executeSearch">
    <s:textfield key="searchBean.name" label="Name"/>
    <s:textfield key="searchbean.age"  label="Age"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>

<s:form action="executeRegister">
    <s:textfield key="firstName" label="First Name"/>
    <s:textfield key="lastName" label="Last Name"/>
    <s:textfield key="age" label="Age"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

<sub>Note: the `key` attribute generates `name`, `label`, and `value`.</sub>

Each action needs to initialize a `searchBean`, unless it has a session scope. If you put a bean to a session, then you should use `#session.` prefix.  More about [OGNL](http://struts.apache.org/docs/ognl.html) you can find on the docs page.

Comment: Thanks, Roman, for your answer. However I am still in the dark about how to achieve that. There is no problem if I have a singe action. I know the action can have many methods which I can for instance map to multiple submit buttons in a form.
But in my case I have two completely separate forms, models and their action classes which do the initialization, verification and so on. And I need to have both on the same page. I added an example how I am trying to do it. Maybe you can steer me in the right direction?

Comment: In most cases Struts is used to prepare the value stack to keep the components shown by the view and each one should have a unique OGNL path to access it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That steered my in the right direction. I wrote down my solution in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I found (please correct me): Two forms need to be initiated in their own actions before be show to user, when you ask for Registration form, the search form does not get initiated, as its action is never called.

This is a common problem which can be easily handled with Ajax, DO NOT LOAD ALL YOUR PAGE DATA. Please have a look at http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action. There is a Theme selection select box, which has been initiated once. Loading other part of the page, will be done via Ajax and thus the theme selection, action which initiates the select box, does not need to be re-run. You can easily use the struts 2 jquery plugin to achieve it.

If you can not use Ajax (with any reason), then there is no simple way. You should manually initiate the you search form items, in EACH action, to make sure that your struts tag can read search form initiated data. You can think of it as you need to some how, cut and paste the body of your search action in all your actions !!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I am giving an answer to my own question. After a lot more of Google time, I found that initializing the secondary action with `<s:action />` inside the JSP does what I need. This tag can also return the action object in a variable, which we can push on the `ValueStack` for the form. An example looks like this:

```
<!-- Initializes search model (preloading and stuff). -->
<s:action var="searchAction" name="inputSearch" >
    <s:param name="origin" value="inputRegister"/>
</s:action>

<!-- Pushing search action on ValueStack for the search form. -->
<s:push value="#searchAction">
    <s:form action="executeSearch">
        <s:hidden name="origin"/>
        <s:textfield key="name" label="Name"/>
        <s:textfield key="age"  label="Age"/>
        <s:submit/>
    </s:form>
</s:push>

<!-- This is the main form. It knows nothing about the search action. -->
<s:form action="executeRegister">
    <s:textfield key="firstName" label="First Name"/>
    <s:textfield key="lastName" label="Last Name"/>
    <s:textfield key="age" label="Age"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

This works nice. However there are two issues which need to be considered:

- The search action is used in many pages. If the validation of the search form fails, we need to find back to the original page. I solved this by having an "origin" parameter. This is set to the main input action`s name. The search action chains to this action if validation fails.
- The search action is initialized very late, when the rendering of the JSP is already in full progress. Exceptions at this point can be problematic. I had to take care to catch all Exceptions myself.

Comment: Very hacky solution to very simple requirement.

Comment: Yes. I am still struggling to find a good way for this. I want the actions to be completely decoupled. But still need to have them is the same view. I am open to better suggestions. (Alireza's solution is nice, but unfortunately not possible).

Comment: *I want the actions to be completely decoupled* - Why? You can have one action which will populate both forms and separate actions for submitting from forms.

Comment: That's right, why do I need another action to populate another form? I will do it in one action.

Comment: But that means I need an extra action for every other form. Or melt the search functionality into every other action. That doesn't seem very modular.

Comment: You can create some base action which your other actions extend. And if you need to add search to different pages then you should NOT populate it from the action scope.